# how to echo out time in codeigniter based on timezone?

Tags: codeigniter-2

how to echo out time in codeigniter based on timezone ?

Answer (score 3):

First, set your master time reference to 'GMT' in your config file:

```
$config['time_reference'] = 'gmt';
```

Choose from timezone reference in http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html or use the timezone_menu() to set a variable or update a DB column for $timezone in the code below:

```
$time = now();  
$timezone = 'UM5';  
$daylight_saving = TRUE; // or FALSE  
$local_time = unix_to_human(gmt_to_local($time, $timezone, $daylight_saving));  
echo $local_time;
```